# javascript: public array with object

Tags: javascript, arrays

(sorry for my english=/)
I create an array when 'onload'.

(this:

```
var $ = {
    ratio: 0.7,
    screen: 500,
    margin: 10,
    canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx: document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
}
```

and `$.canvas` and `$.ctx` is give 'null'.
this work if i rewrite it

```
...
canvas: function(){return document.getElementById("canvas")}
...
```

but if i want to call this the variable looks like this $.canvas **()**
how can i make this variable without '()'???

Comment: appears that canvas is not loaded yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a problem with the scope of your `$` variable. By declaring it with the `var` keyword inside the `window.onload` function, its scope is the local function and not the global scope.

You could define it outside of the onload function instead:

```
var $; // in the global scope

window.onload = function(){
    $ = {
        ratio: 0.7,
        screen: 500,
        margin: 10,
        canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx: document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")
    };

    console.log($.canvas);
    console.log($.ctx);
};
```

By declaring it in the global scope, it can be accessed from outside of the onload function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZP8s/2/)

Comment: I don't think it's a scope problem. OP says it works if he assigns a function to `$.canvas`. If it was a scope problem, then the error would be something like `Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.$ = {
        ratio: 0.7,
        screen: 500,
        margin: 10,
        canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx: document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    }
}
```